# SQL Update, update inserted data from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure whether my approach is correct or not. I have two table, A and B. I need to create ID on table A then the details on table B. Column ID in table A is auto incremented.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE A (DESCRIPTION)
SELECT REPLACE(DESCRIPTION, 100, @INCREMENT)
FROM TABLE A
```

Now I have created the ID in table A, I need to create new row on table B based on  EXISTING data on table B. Below is my query.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE B (ID, JOBCODE)
SELECT ID, JOBCODE
FROM TABLE B INNER JOIN TABLE A ON A.ID = B.ID
```

How do I update the recently created row on table B so it match the ID on table A.

Comment: You need a SELECT section in your insert into B.

Comment: You can declare a variable to scope_identity(), get the inserted ID and use it later

Comment: You ask "How do I update" but are doing an INSERT? Are you looking to insert new data, or update existing?

Comment: You may need to use cursors

Comment: @BlueGI select statement added

Comment: @Ivan-San      thank you for your suggestion, however scope_identity is not suitable for my scenario since the data inserted could be more than one at a time.

Comment: @alexherm i will look into into it. thanks. For now I handled it temporarily using temp table.